# What ruby type to store bit mask? In migrations, what do I use bigint or?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a bit mask for permissions, what is the data type I use in my rails migration?

In sql server I used bigint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most Rails apps are on MySQL so I'm guessing that's the data store you're asking about.  MySQL also has a BigInt type.  How big are the bit mask values you're planing to store?  It sounds like you want some integer value of a size big enough for your bitmask.

Here's the full details on numeric data types in MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

EDIT: The code to specify this via Rails schema DSL in a migration would be:

```
add_column(:my_table, :bitmask, :integer, :precision => 20)
# => bitmask DECIMAL(20)
# 20 digit integer, holds 64bit value
```

Comment: I was hoping for 64 bits, so I can store 63 different permissions.